# Why should tech firms get away with publishing child pornography and facilitating child sex grooming rings?

Tags: social-media, public-law

I read a recent newspaper report that the UK police force were dealing with **roughly 80,000 cases of online child sex grooming**.

If newspapers, or publishing firms published child pornography there were be a massive uproar. Likewise with tv stations and film studios.

However tech firms it seems can get away with publishing child pornography and facilitating such grooming rings almost with impunity. Their argument is generally that they provide a resource and can't be held responsible for the behaviour of users. They say that they facilitate 'sharing' whilst eliding over the very visible fact that bad practises can be shared too.

Surely that is an argument that is wearing very thin now. If it takes more man-power than they have readily to hand - well surely they should hire more people. They make enough money as it is. I'll believe Mark Zuckerbergs catchism on 'sharing' when he substantially shares out his massive fortune.

Is there any kind of legal pressure that can be applied on tech firms so that they take a much more proactive line in moderation rather than simply relying on the **unpaid and untrained labour** of thousands of people? If not, does this mean that the legal profession needs to start looking at how such laws can be framed?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on https://politics.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @BlueDogRanch: It belongs here because I'm asking what legal measure are available and why they are not being used. There is an overlap between law and politics of course - which is why quite often lawyers become politicians.

Comment: The legal measure concerned is called https://www.eff.org/issues/cda230 To change the law takes political action.

Comment: @BlueDogRanch: That assumes that the law needs changing. Maybe it doesn't? Perhaps there are useful measures that are already on the books but aren't being simply used.For example, one question that I heard a European lawmaker was to ask why they simply shouldn't break up the tech firms. I gather those measures are already under the books under anti-trust.

Comment: Your last paragraph contains two questions; the first question confuses the role of prosecutors, the current law and the business practice of some tech companies using what is called the sharing economy; and the second question is political in that is involves the framing, as you say, of the laws themselves, which is to say the legislative process to amend or change laws.

Comment: @bluedogranch: The questions are related. You're hair-splitting.

Comment: Law SE functions with questions that clearly demonstrate how they are related to the law.

Comment: @BlueDogRanch: Are you saying law concerned with publishing is outside the the remit of Law. SE?

Comment: Is this question specific to UK law?

Comment: @IllusiveBrain: Not particularly. You can take a comparative law approach if you find that useful strategy to answer.

Comment: One reason why the author of this question didn't post this question on Politics Stack Exchange might be that [the user is currently suspended there](https://politics.stackexchange.com/users/3164/mozibur-ullah).

Comment: The only hope that I see for reformulating the question is to drop the unproven assertion that tech firms publish child porn, and ask what changes in law (specify a jurisdiction) would be required to make a tech firm criminally liable if their product was used in the production and distribution of child porn (with a note that this would be a strict liability crime).

Comment: @user6726: **But I never said it was proven. It is easily understood what I mean by this - as by your own reformulation of what I said - and that is the important part of it**.

Comment: @phillip: That is correct. I also note that in the original detention I was not told what I was being suspended for and nor for what period. It seems now that they have decided that the period of suspension is up to mid Feb '19. Nevertheless, I am annoyed as to why the legal profession are being backward in tackling the abuses in the online era - and that justifies this question - and the ordinary laymens language in asking this question.

Comment: @MoziburUllah, anyhow, you could rewrite the question, or we can leave things as they stand. You say that "get away with publishing child pornography". That's a factual assertion.

Comment: @user 6726: There is nothing wrong with the question as it stands. I am going to leave as is.

Answer (score 4):

Social media platforms are **not** publishers under UK law (at [present](https://www.theguardian.com/technology/2017/oct/11/government-considers-classifying-google-facebook-publishers)), as such, they are not legally responsible for the content they host providing that there is a mechanism for alerting them to infringing material and that, when alerted, they remove it.

As to "why", that is a political question.

Comment: **-1: I disagree - it a legal question. What what would make this a much better answer is providing the legal justification as to why social media platforms are not legally considered publishers, including dissenting opinions.**

Comment: They are not legally publishers because politicians around the world have decided they aren’t and written laws to give effect to that decision

Comment: I did not say *legally* understood as publishers. Apparently, once a senate decided that pi was legally defined to be 3.14. Mathematicians just fell over themselves laughing at their stupidity.